# Getting audio from microphone

Tags: c, audio, posix, microphone

What is most portable way to get audio from microphone across free, POSIX-compilant 
OS? I really confused with OSS(deprecated?), ALSA, JACK, PulseAudio. Which of them should I use?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think there is no good portable way, make that an answer.

Comment: I don't think POSIX particulary contemplated audio capture... So there's not going to be a "standard" way. On top of that, each OS abstracts the underlying hardware in different ways, so a portable solution isn't particularly easy.

Answer (score 1):

[ALSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) provides the low level API for Linux. Similar to [DirectSound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectSound) for Windows. 
If you want to use low level features and have full control use ALSA. Otherwise its API is difficult to use in my opinion.

Check out source code of [PJSIP](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf) which is portable across Linux and Windows (in C language).
In this project you will see how ALSA is wrapped for easier interfaces.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice information, thanks. But I wrote I have no interest in Windows.
More intresting, what about BSD descedants.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **standard** way to do this.  There are no formal standards for sound APIs.

The best you can *hope* for is an API that are available across a wide enough range of families / versions / releases of Linux and Bsd to be satisfactory.  The history of this problem space means that its is pretty much guaranteed that no single API will give you full coverage.

My recommendation would be to restrict yourself to mainstream / modern operating systems and leave the older / least used stuff for someone else to deal with.  And release your code as open source ... so that the *can* address the problem of porting it.